# How to sort an array based on values of another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array that has following values

```
Nata_sha_AD8_02_ABA
Jack_DD2_03_K
Alex_AD8_01_PO
Mary_CD3_03_DC
John_DD2_01_ER
Daniel_AD8_04_WS
```

I want to group them based on following array ['AD8','CD3','DD2','PD0']; and sort each group based on number of each value. So the output should be

```
Alex_AD8_01_PO
Nata_sha_AD8_02_ABA 
Daniel_AD8_04_WS
Mary_CD3_03_DC
John_DD2_01_ER
Jack_DD2_03_K
```

So far, I wrote following code, but it does not work properly, and I am stuck here.

```
var temparr = [];
var order = 1000;
var pos = -1;
var temp = -1;
var filterArray= ['AD8','CD3','DD2','PD0'];
 for (i =0; i< filterArray.length; i++) {
    for (j =0; j < myarray.length; j++) {
        if(filterArray[i].toUpperCase().search(myarray[j])>0){
          temp = str.substring(myarray[j].indexOf(filterArray[i])+4, myarray[j].indexOf(filterArray[i]+6); 
          if(temp < order){
            pos = j;
            order = temp;
          }
          if(j == myarray.length-1){ //reached end of the loop
              temparr.push(myarray[pos]);
              order = 1000;
          }
        }        
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is that sorting array `filterArray` itself deliberately in alphabetical order, or is that just a coincidence?

Comment: @Alnitak this array  ['AD8','CD3','DD2','PD0'] is deliberately sorted.

Comment: @Jack and the suffixes are always in the format `_XXN_NN` ?

Comment: @Alnitak yes I will update the question

Comment: If my suspicions  are correct you've been making this *way* too hard for yourself! :)

Comment: OK, where did those extra suffices on the values come from?  That changes the question somewhat.

Comment: @Alnitak Sorry, I forgot to include them they are random suffix.

Comment: Is the underscore before the `_XXN_NN` part always the first underscore in the string?

Comment: @Alnitak no might not be, I changed natasha to clarify that.

Comment: Is the length of the string after the name of constant length? e.g. NA_ME_otherstuff (otherstuff is constant length?)

Comment: @Sphaso No it is not constant, as you see natasha has 3 characters at the end and the rest just two.

Comment: Is there any way you can have them speparate before you have them in the same string? e.g. {name: 'Nata_sha', code: 'A..' }

Comment: All that info would have been welcome before posting my answer lol :) I'll leave it there anyways I guess

Comment: @Salketer after a while here, you learn when not to make assumptions about the example input that the OP has shown you ;-)

Comment: lol yeh! I need to find the sweet spot between that and trying to be first to answer!

Comment: @Jack you appear to have accepted an answer that doesn't actually work

Comment: @Alnitak have not had time to test it, I just accepted it based on the code snippet, will unaccept it and after testing will do it again.

Answer (score 1):

On the basis that the filtering array is in alphabetical order, and that every string has a substring in the format `_XXN_NN_` that you actually want to sort on, it should be sufficient simply to sort based on extracting that substring, without reference to `filterArray`:

```js
var names = ['Nata_sha_AD8_02_ABA', 'Jack_DD2_03_K', 'Alex_AD8_01_PO', 'Mary_CD3_03_DC', 'John_DD2_01_ER', 'Daniel_AD8_04_WS'];

names.sort(function(a, b) {
  var re = /_((AD8|CD3|DD2|PD0)_\d\d)_/;
  a = a.match(re)[1];
  b = b.match(re)[1];
  return a.localeCompare(b);
});

alert(names);
```

Comment: I am sorry, I had to mention the string would be quite longer.

Comment: I think OP wants to sort for b first, then a. See how Alex precedes Natasha

Comment: @Sphaso that's fine, since it sorts on the `01` as well as `PO`.   The extra bits on the end need some work, though!

Comment: Alex and Natasha are both in AD8 group, Alex precedes Natasha because its number is 1.

Comment: @Sphaso they are sorted based on numbers of each group.

Answer (score 1):

Using the first `sort` parameter you can pass a function to run to sort the array. This function receives 2 values of the array, and should compare them and return less than 0 if the first is lower than the second, higher than 0 if it is higher, or 0 if they are the same. In my proposition, I split the name and "token" part of the values, and then compare the tokens to order them correctly. Using the `indexOf` on the filterArray allows me to compare the position of the tags accordingly.

```js
var array_to_sort = ['Natasha_AD8_02',
  'Jack_DD2_03',
  'Alex_AD8_01',
  'Mary_CD3_03',
  'John_DD2_01',
  'Daniel_AD8_04'
];

var filterArray = ['AD8', 'CD3', 'DD2', 'PD0'];

array_to_sort.sort(function(a, b) {
  a_token = a.substr(a.indexOf('_')+1); //Remove the name part as it is useless
  b_token = b.substr(b.indexOf('_')+1);//Remove the name part as it is useless
  if(a_token.substr(0,3) == b_token.substr(0,3)){//If the code is the same, order by the following numbers
    if(a_token > b_token){return 1;}
    if(a_token < b_token){return -1;}
    return 0;
  }else{ //Compare the position in the filterArray of each code.
    if(filterArray.indexOf(a_token.substr(0,3)) > filterArray.indexOf(b_token.substr(0,3))){return 1;}
    if(filterArray.indexOf(a_token.substr(0,3)) < filterArray.indexOf(b_token.substr(0,3))){return -1;}
    return 0;
  }
});


document.write(array_to_sort);
```

EDIT: This method will sort in a way that the filterArray can be in any order, and dictates the order wanted. After updates from OP this may not be the requirement... EDIT2: the question being modified more and more, this solution will not work.

Answer (score 1):

My solution.
The only restriction this solution has has is that your sort array has to be sorted already. The `XXn_nn` part can be anywhere in the string, but it assumes the `nn` part always follows the `XXn` part (like `DD3_17`).

```
var result=new Array();
var p,x;

    //loop the 'search' array
for(var si=0,sl=sort.length;si<sl;si++){

    //create new tmp array
    var tmp=new Array();

    //loop the data array
    for(var ai=0,al=arr.length;ai<al;ai++){
        var el=arr[ai];
        //test if element still exists
        if(typeof el=='undefined' || el=='')continue;

        //test if element has 'XXn_nn' part 
        if(arr[ai].indexOf(sort[si]) > -1){
            //we don't now where the 'XXn_nn' part is, so we split on '_' and look for it
            x=el.split('_');
            p=x.indexOf(sort[si]);
            //add element to tmp array on position nn
            tmp[parseInt(x[p+1])]=el;
            //remove element from ariginal array, making sure we don't check it again
            arr.splice(ai,1);ai--;
            }
    }
    //remove empty's from tmp array
    tmp=tmp.filter(function(n){return n!=undefined}); 
    //add to result array
    result=result.concat(tmp);
}
```

And a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vta4nw6t/)